# slideToggle with $.cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, slidetoggle

This is a piece of code I worked up for a panel on our Forums, it worked from July 2012 to probably December 2012 until I noticed it no longer works... Did something change? FYI  have jquery.cookie.mini.js installed in our template folder for PHPBB if that's relevant.

```
<script>

    // Open / Close Panel According to Cookie //    
    if ($.cookie('streamshow') == 'open' || $.cookie('streamshow') == null){    
        /*$('.slide').slideDown('fast'); // Show on Page Load / Refresh with Animation*/
        $('#streamslide').show(); // Show on Page Load / Refresh without Animation
    } else {
        /*$('.slide').slideUp('fast'); // Hide on Page Load / Refresh with Animation*/
        $('#streamslide').hide(); // Hide on Page Load / Refresh without Animation
    }

    // Toggle Panel and Set Cookie //
    $('#streamclk').click(function(){        
        $('#streamslide').slideToggle('fast', function(){
            if ($('#streamclk').is(':hidden')) {
                $.cookie('streamshow', 'close', { expires: 30 });
            } else {
                $.cookie('streamshow', 'open');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: 1) what jquery version from where are you using? 2) if edge, add the migrate js file. 3) anything in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referencing a jQuery library that is hosted somewhere that no longer supports cookies? Did it get modified?  Did an automatic update run and update your library?

Check out all of the referenced jQuery libraries you have on your page.  There is about 4 of them in total I can count and the last referenced library is 1.5.1.

Comment: as far as im aware, all the js files needed are currently installed and being called from the overall_header file.

Comment: Are the elements #streamclk and #streamslide still in the dom?  Can you see them if you inspect the live page?

Comment: Yes they are still there. The page is http://teamewix.com it is the top "Live Streams" section/DIV

Comment: Wow... I think i found my error...   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Well from looking at your source you have about 4 references to jquery core libraries there.  The last referenced library is 1.5.1

Comment: Very strange, I have no idea how this <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> got there. Or why its even there. And if it was there when the code was working X amount of days ago.

Comment: Looks like those cookie errors went away, theres still a couple of unrelated errors in the console though.  Make sure those are attended to also.

Comment: Also I would always try and use one recent jQUERY library at a time to reduce page load

Comment: Great, Thanks for all your help, I think I was able to nail down most those errors you speak of, not sure why tapatalkdetect.js would be erroring, or why styleswitcher.js has an error either.